# Convert timestamp to string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event for the scheduler that will perform two actions every two minutes:

1. Upload data from the City table to a separate file with the current date
2. Create a mark in the table about the created file

Currently trying to use the following query

```
CREATE EVENT city_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
DO 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM world_innodb.City INTO OUTFILE CONCAT (“C: \\ mysql \\ City_”, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO test_event (event time) SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
END;
```

There was a problem in type conversion when using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the CONCAT function. How can I convert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to a string, or maybe there is another way to write a file with the current date in the name?

Comment: Current_timestamp returns the timestamp as a string if the output is used in a string environment. However, the : in the output is not allowed in windows file names, so this may be an issue if you are using windows - which seems to be a case.

Comment: Remove these strange double quotes from `“C: \\ mysql \\ City_”` and use single quotes: `'C: \\ mysql \\ City_'`

Answer (score 0):

for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP could be you just need  to replace some chars properly

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'/',''),'-',''),' ','_'),':','');
```

or as suggested  by @Shadow  a more easy way is date_format()

```
select date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%Y%m%d_%H%i%s')
```